# OpenCL oil painting

Tags: opencl

I want to implement oil painting filter in OpenCL,but the output image is always black and I cannot figure out why.
Here's the kernel code:

```
__kernel void oil_painting(__global const char* R,__global const char* G,__global const char* B,
                 __global char* r,__global char* g,__global char* b)
{
    int i=get_global_id(0);
    int j=get_global_id(1);
    int i1,j1,k;

    int avgR[256],avgG[256],avgB[256],intensity_count[256];
    int max_pixels=0,max_intensity=0,current_intensity;

    for (i1=0;i1<4;i1++) {
        for (j1=0;j1<4;j1++) {
            current_intensity=(((R[(i+i1)*512+j+j1]+
                                 G[(i+i1)*512+j+j1]+
                                 B[(i+i1)*512+j+j1])/3)*70)/255;
            intensity_count[current_intensity]++;

            if (intensity_count[current_intensity]>max_pixels) {
                max_pixels=intensity_count[current_intensity];
                max_intensity=current_intensity;
            }

            avgR[current_intensity]+=R[(i+i1)*512+j+j1];
            avgG[current_intensity]+=G[(i+i1)*512+j+j1];
            avgB[current_intensity]+=B[(i+i1)*512+j+j1];
        }
    }

    r[i*512+j]=min(255,max(0,avgR[max_intensity]/max_pixels));
    g[i*512+j]=min(255,max(0,avgG[max_intensity]/max_pixels));
    b[i*512+j]=min(255,max(0,avgB[max_intensity]/max_pixels));
}
```

Comment: You should really be using the built-in Image objects (`image2d_t` comes to mind), not these constructs where you've manually split every channel into its own buffer.

Comment: @Xirema it's possible that's the format of his source data.

Answer (score 2):

Code snippets like the following are going to get you into a lot of trouble:

```
current_intensity=(((R[(i+i1)*512+j+j1]+
                     G[(i+i1)*512+j+j1]+
                     B[(i+i1)*512+j+j1])/3)*70)/255;
```

Consider what happens for a pixel of <127,127,127>:

```
127 + 127 + 127 = 125 (truncated because `char` is only 8 bytes...)
125 / 3 = 41
41 * 70 = 54 (truncated because `char` is only 8 bytes...)
54 / 255 = 0 (this will always equal 0!)
```

So `intensity_count` will only ever have its 0-th index incremented, and nothing else.

Casting everything to `int` might fix this problem.

```
current_intensity=((((int)R[(i+i1)*512+j+j1]+
                     (int)G[(i+i1)*512+j+j1]+
                     (int)B[(i+i1)*512+j+j1])/3)*70)/255;
```

New output:

```
127 + 127 + 127 = 381
381 / 3 = 127
127 * 70 = 8890
8890 / 255 = 34
```

But you've now got a new problem: what if the values are any higher than 127? Suppose we change this to use <200, 200, 200> instead?

```
-56 + -56 + -56 = -168 (`char` only has a range in [-128, 127]! You're overflowing!)
-168 / 3 = -56
-56 * 70 = -3920
-3920 / 255 = -15
```

And now you've crashed your program because either you're going to attempt to access index `-15`, which is illegal, or you're going to attempt to access index `2^64 - 15 - 1`, which is going to still be illegal. Either way, you're going to get bad results.

The simplest solution is to change your kernel arguments to `global uchar *` instead of `global char *`, and then make sure that any and all arithmetic is casted upwards to `int` or `long` to ensure that overflow doesn't take place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.It partially improved my code and helped me understand what was wrong.There are still some pixels missing from the output,but I'll fix it.